# css and php displaying fonts from folder

Tags: css, fonts

i understand its a bit rude to ask a question from scratch however i have done my research and tried a few examples with no sucess.

im trying to display a font from my local servers.

ex. DigitaldreamNarrow.ttf

which is located in :

css/fonts/DigitaldreamNarrow.ttf

i have tried placing it in my css file in the following manner:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: DigitaldreamNarrow;
  src: url(‘css/fonts/DigitaldreamNarrow.ttf’);
}
.top {
  font-family: DigitaldreamNarrow;
  font-size: 0.2%;
}
```

however at this point im lost and i dont see any results in my display.

help?

Answer (score 1):

Deploying fonts via CSS is generally unsupported. Take a look at Cufon.

Comment: any other way other than javascript?

Answer (score 0):

@trey, write this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DigitaldreamNarrow';
  src: url(‘../css/fonts/DigitaldreamNarrow.ttf’);
}
```

may there is a problem with your url please it.

May be you have to add `inverted comma` to the font .

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArvoRegular';
    src: url('Arvo-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('Arvo-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('Arvo-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('Arvo-Regular-webfont.svg#webfontau9vOdrl') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You're going to have different results from different browsers (not all browsers support/use 'eot' for example). Check out font squirrel, and download an @face kit. Very helpful resource. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface

This is more than likely the direction fonts will take, and Cufon will likely become "Gif Builder"...IMO.

Comment: agree. cufon seems too involved